# iOS: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException'

Tags: ios, nsrangeexception

I have searched through a number of these `NSRangeException` error threads but can't seem to find an answer to my question. Here is my error:

> 2015-08-15 17:28:43.793 UTK Recruiting[8794:254203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Here is a couple of bits of code. Basically I am going through the documents directories, getting all the filenames and paths, and then I'm trying to populate `UITableView` with the filenames so a cell can be selected, and then that file can be attached to an email. Here are a few bits of my code:

Parses documents directory, puts all csv files in corresponding arrays.

```
- (void) refreshTable {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *documentArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

    NSArray *csvFiles = [documentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [evaluatedObject hasSuffix:@".csv"];
    }]];

    self.csvFileNames = (NSMutableArray*) csvFiles;
    self.csvFilePaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[csvFiles count]];

    for (NSString *fileName in csvFiles) {
        [self.csvFilePaths addObject:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];
    }



    NSLog(@"files array %@", _csvFileNames);
    NSLog(@"files array %@", _csvFilePaths);
```

This is the UITableView code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"count: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.csvFileNames count]);
    return [self.csvFileNames count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellforRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text=[self.csvFileNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

After placing break points throughout my code, I've found that it crashes in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, which is the last method in the code I posted. Something else important to note is that there are 4 csv files, and `[self.csvFileNames count]` correctly gives the number 4.

The code should be running until index 3, but I can't figure out why it is not.

> - thread #1: tid = 0x40646, 0x000000010de9f286 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
>     frame #0: 0x000000010de9f286 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
>     frame #1: 0x000000010ded242f libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 90
>     frame #2: 0x000000010dc3f19a libsystem_sim_c.dylib`abort + 129
>     frame #3: 0x000000010da2a481 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 257
>     frame #4: 0x000000010da523d5 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 267
>     frame #5: 0x0000000106aeae19 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 103
>     frame #6: 0x000000010da4fb01 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
>     frame #7: 0x000000010da4f7aa libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 99
>     frame #8: 0x0000000106aead2c libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 40
>     frame #9: 0x0000000106d7a41e CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 654
>     frame #10: 0x0000000109b13a3e GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
>     frame #11: 0x000000010724a8c0 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1282
>
>   - frame #12: 0x000000010640211f UTK Recruiting`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff598014f8) + 111 at main.m:14
>       frame #13: 0x000000010db97145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
>       frame #14: 0x000000010db97145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1

bt all crash report:

> - thread #1: tid = 0x56469, 0x0000000109200286 >libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop >reason = signal SIGABRT
>     frame #0: 0x0000000109200286 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
>     frame #1: 0x000000010923342f libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 90
>     frame #2: 0x0000000108fa019a libsystem_sim_c.dylib`abort + 129
>     frame #3: 0x0000000108d8b481 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 257
>     frame #4: 0x0000000108db33d5 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 267
>     frame #5: 0x0000000101e4be19 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 103
>     frame #6: 0x0000000108db0b01 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
>     frame #7: 0x0000000108db07aa libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 99
>     frame #8: 0x0000000101e4bd2c libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 40
>     frame #9: 0x00000001020db41e CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 654
>     frame #10: 0x0000000104e74a3e GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
>     frame #11: 0x00000001025ab8c0 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1282
>
>   - frame #12: 0x000000010176311f UTK Recruiting`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5e4a04f8) + 111 at main.m:14
>       frame #13: 0x0000000108ef8145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
>       frame #14: 0x0000000108ef8145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
>
>   thread #2: tid = 0x564a0, 0x0000000109201232 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 10, queue = 'com.apple.libdispatch-manager'
>     frame #0: 0x0000000109201232 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 10
>     frame #1: 0x0000000108eb376c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 247
>     frame #2: 0x0000000108eb3511 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread + 54
>
>   thread #3: tid = 0x564a2, 0x000000010920094a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
>     frame #0: 0x000000010920094a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
>     frame #1: 0x00000001092316c3 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 869
>     frame #2: 0x000000010922f40d libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13
>
>   thread #4: tid = 0x564a3, 0x000000010920094a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
>     frame #0: 0x000000010920094a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
>     frame #1: 0x00000001092316c3 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 869
>     frame #2: 0x000000010922f40d libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13
>
>   thread #5: tid = 0x564a4, 0x000000010920094a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
>     frame #0: 0x000000010920094a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
>     frame #1: 0x00000001092316c3 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 869
>     frame #2: 0x000000010922f40d libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13
>
>   thread #6: tid = 0x564a5, 0x000000010920094a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
>     frame #0: 0x000000010920094a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
>     frame #1: 0x00000001092316c3 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 869
>     frame #2: 0x000000010922f40d libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13

Comment: I'd try setting a breakpoint on the `cell.textLabel.text=...` line and using `po self.csvFileNames` to see what the array contained each time through (or use NSLog).

Comment: I would, but unfortunately the method does not appear to work it all. It crashes immediately no matter where I put the break point in the method.

Comment: Try printing out the output of indexPath in cellForRowAtIndexPath, before anything. The crash is most likely caused by the dequeReusableCellWithIdentifer.

Comment: That's suspicious.  When it crashes, type `bt` in your debug console and add the results to your question.

Comment: Added, I also added the print statement and set a breakpoint at it, but it did not run.

Comment: OK, I'm confused too.  The crashing thread is off handling some graphics event and nowhere near your code.  One more try...what do you see if you use `bt all` instead?  (Maybe something's happening in the background.)

Comment: How is `refreshTable` called?  Is it possible that it is running at the same time as your table is being populated?

Comment: how is your variable `csvFileNames` declared? can you post the line?

Comment: refreshTable is called in viewDidLoad, and then it is called anytime a button is pressed to update the view. cvsFileNames is declared in the .h file as @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *csvFileNames.

Comment: I'll post the bt all crash report when I am back in civilization which will be tomorrow

Comment: I've posted the bt all crash report

Comment: I don't appreciate the down votes on my question....

Answer (score 0):

Change your cellforRowAtIndexPath method :-

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

Comment: It is still crashing with the same error. I don't see how this fixes the problem of the code indexing beyond the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

`refreshTable` appears to be building the array `self.csvFilePaths` correctly, but your cellForRowAtIndexPath is referencing `self.csvFileNames` and I don't see where that is being populated.

The range exception is telling you that you don't have 4 objects in `self.csvFileNames`.

To make your life a lot easier going forward, add the "All Exceptions" breakpoint to your project. Go to the Breakpoint Navigator (Command 7). At the bottom, click + and choose "Add Exception Breakpoint." When your code runs, it will break on the exception before it is thrown.

Comment: self.csvFileNames = (NSMutableArray*) csvFiles; is the line that populates self.csvFileNames, which is right above where self.csvFilePaths is populated. You'll notice that I have a print statement: NSLog(@"files array %@", _csvFileNames); it prints out the following: 
"Change Event Name.csv",
    "f.csv",
    "it.csv",
    "j.csv"

It correctly prints the 4 files found in the document directories folder, so I find it hard to believe that, that is the issue. I even put a print statement above the return statement in numbersOfRowsInSection, and it prints the number 4.

Comment: Didn't notice that. Possibly then the problem is you are casting an Array into a Mutable Array which is allowed by the compiler, but not a good idea. Try `self.csvFileNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:csvFiles];` and see what happens